# How to graph this function's Riemann surface with Mathematica

Tags: plotting, special-functions, complex

I was studying Riemann surfaces, when I found this fancy plot

[image: Rs]

Sadly the only specification of the figure was this miser caption

> Riemann surface for $$W(z)^{d}+W(z)+z^{d-1}$$ with $d=5$

where $W(z)$ is the Lambert $W$ function defined as :

$$z = W(z)e^{W(z)}$$

Now my question is:

- What could be on the three axes? I mean, what  have you to plot to visualise the Riemann surface of $W(z)^{d}+W(z)+z^{d-1}$ shown above in [the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LYs3.gif)?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: This was done by Michael Trott circa 2003 I believe. I'll have to look for the old code that was used on the Wolfram Functions site. Since it was written for version 5, it will likely need a lot of adjustment to make it work for the current version of *Mathematica*.

Comment: The code for the plot is in the [first google search result](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSurface.html) for "Riemann surface".  I downloaded the notebook, pulled [this code](https://git.io/v7DnD) from it, which when evaluated creates this plot.  To understand the code, what it's plotting, etc, will require some work on your part.